# Problema ao utilizar o Identity em API ASP .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, injeção-de-dependência

Boa tarde, estou tentando utilizar o Identity na minha API, porém estou com algum erro que acredito ser de injeção de dependência.

Fiz toda a configuração necessária, conectei com o banco, gerei os Migrations, porém quando tento injetar as classes SignInManager e UserManager do Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity na minha Controller, estou tomando um erro de ArgumentNullException na Startup, assim como imagem abaixo.

[image: ArgumentNullException]

O erro da entender que a aplicação não esta conseguindo acessar a string dentro do appsettings, porém para aplicar os Migrations está funcionando.

Se eu remover SignInManager e UserManager da Controller o erro para de ocorrer. Segue implementações:

Startup:

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AppDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

AppDbContext:

```
namespace Identity.API.Data
{
  public class AppDbContext : IdentityDbContext
  {
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : 
    base(options) {}
  }
}
```

appsettings (saiu meio desformatado):

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection":
    "Server= (localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=MyDb;
      Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Controller (estou testando um método simples GET):

```
namespace Identity.API.Controllers
{
   [ApiController]
   [Route("auth")]
   public class AuthController : Controller
   {
     public readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> SignInManager;
     public readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager;

     public AuthController(
        SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
        UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
     {
        SignInManager = signInManager;
        UserManager = userManager;
     }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Deu certo";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Você verificou se o método `GetConnectionString()` está retornando o valor correto? A base de dados e as tabelas foram criadas no banco?

Comment: Sim, foram criadas normalmente. Qualquer migration que eu aplico, da certo. Inclusive se eu passar a string de conexão direto na UseSqlServer() da o mesmo erro, por isso não estou conseguindo entender o erro.

Comment: Pessoal, o erro acontece quando uso debugger do VS Code. Quando eu rodo pelo terminal 'dotnet run' o erro não ocorre. Agora vou descobrir o porque.

Comment: não é a variavel de ambiente?

Answer (score 0):

Se estiver usando o asp.net core 3.1

O Startup:

```
services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<MeuDbContext>();
```

Veja se você tem instalado

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores" Version="3.1.7" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.11" />
```